# You need to run build with JDK or have tools .Jar

Tags: java, xml, maven, servlets, spring-data-jpa

[in this part of POM.xml, i am getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GXQV.jpg)Getting below error in pom.xml:

You need to run build with JDK or have tools .Jar  on the class path...

** I have already tried adding JDK as jre path

**Also added tools.jar in the

Configure build path - external lib

But had no luck...

Comment: Set JAVA_HOME environment variable to JDK directory, Maven uses it to find JDK

Comment: Can you run `javac` with no arguments on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
Try `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x_xx"` or `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x_xx\jre` instead of `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`

**Solution 2:**
[Edit](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) `eclipse.ini` file

```
-vm
C:\jdk1.7\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: Had already tried editing eclipse 
Ini
-vm C:

-vm C:\jdk1.7\bin\javaw.exe

But no luck

Comment: Are you use eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

```
In Eclipse 
------------

Go to properties --> Java build path -->Add the JDK Don't add the jre.build and check.If not run build path double click the jre system library --> select the Installed JRE -->select edit ----> Add the external jar -->go to the java installed path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\lib select tools.jar .Now build it 

**Add the dependency**

<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution> 
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
      <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: add the dependency and check it

Comment: This is not great advice. Using Maven `system` scoped dependencies is considered poor practice and the capability may disappear in future versions of Maven. @EvgeniyDorofeev 's advice is the way to go.